# Unique on a dataframe with only selected columns

Tags: r, unique

I have a dataframe with >100 columns, and I would to find the unique rows by comparing only two of the columns. I'm hoping this is an easy one, but I can't get it to work with `unique` or `duplicated` myself.

In the below, I would like to unique only using `id` and `id2`:

```
data.frame(id=c(1,1,3),id2=c(1,1,4),somevalue=c("x","y","z"))

id id2 somevalue
1   1         x
1   1         y
3   4         z
```

I would like to obtain either:

```
id id2 somevalue
1   1         x
3   4         z
```

or:

```
id id2 somevalue
1   1         y
3   4         z
```

(I have no preference which of the unique rows is kept)

Comment: Your desired output isn't well defined. How do you choose to include x but not y? This decision will need to be made for every column of every repeated row, and you've given no indication of how to do it.

Comment: I have no preference whether 'x' or 'y' is included. I'll update the question.

Comment: For `data.table` alternatives: [Filtering out duplicated/non-unique rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Ok, if it doesn't matter which value in the non-duplicated column you select, this should be pretty easy:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,3),id2=c(1,1,4),somevalue=c("x","y","z"))
> dat[!duplicated(dat[,c('id','id2')]),]
  id id2 somevalue
1  1   1         x
3  3   4         z
```

Inside the `duplicated` call, I'm simply passing only those columns from `dat` that I don't want duplicates of. This code will automatically always select the *first* of any ambiguous values. (In this case, x.)

Comment: @Ferroao according to this website, it's not possible in SQL http://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct

Comment: what if the value in the non-duplicated column matters, and we want to keep all the possible combinations?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300005/extract-all-possible-combinations-of-rows-with-unique-values-in-a-variable

Answer (score 42):

Here are a couple `dplyr` options that keep non-duplicate rows based on columns id and id2:

```
library(dplyr)                                        
df %>% distinct(id, id2, .keep_all = TRUE)
df %>% group_by(id, id2) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
df %>% group_by(id, id2) %>% slice(1)
```

Comment: I guess no reason to consider using the alternatives to `distinct`

Comment: @Frank maybe if there is a date or some other sequential field a combination of the two other options with some slight tweaks could be used to ensure the most recent observation is kept `df %>% group_by(id, id2) %>% filter(date == max(date)) %>% slice(1)` without having to sort the data. `filter()` gets the most recent date, `slice()` ensures only one observation is returned if there are ties. In other cases something like `df %>% group_by(id, id2) %>% slice(max(row_number()))` could might give some more flexibility.  You could always use `arrange()` before `distinct()` too.

Comment: @sbha Is there a method to designate a preference for a row with a certain column value when there is a tie in the column you are grouping on? In the case of the example in the question, the row with `somevalue == x` is always returned when the row is a duplicate in the `id` and `id2` columns.

Comment: what if the value in the non-duplicated column matters, and we want to keep all the possible combinations?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300005/extract-all-possible-combinations-of-rows-with-unique-values-in-a-variable

Answer (score 16):

Using `unique()`:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,3),id2=c(1,1,4),somevalue=c("x","y","z"))    
dat[row.names(unique(dat[,c("id", "id2")])),]
```

Comment: `unique(dat[,c("id", "id2")])` returns vector, not dataframe, so you cannot refer to its `row.names`

Comment: @SashkoLykhenko, did you miss the last comma?

Comment: I copypasted this `row.names(unique(dat[,c("id", "id2")]))` and it returned error. Last comma relates to outer `dat[...,]`

Comment: @SashkoLykhenko I try `unique(dat[,c("id", "id2")])`, it's not a vector, it's a dataframe. **But**, the `unique(dat[,c("id")])` will be a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Minor update in @Joran's code.
Using the code below, you can avoid the ambiguity and only get the unique of two columns:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,3), id2=c(1,1,4) ,somevalue=c("x","y","z"))    
dat[row.names(unique(dat[,c("id", "id2")])), c("id", "id2")]
```

Comment: This looks identical to Gary Feng's answer, except that you don't include the `somevalue` result.