# R: Extract unique values in one column grouped by values in another column

Tags: r, data.table

I had thought I could solve this with data.table but looks like it is a bit more difficult. My dataframe looks like this:

```
userID1   A
userID1   A
userID1   B
userID2   A
userID2   A
```

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
userID1   A
userID1   B
userID2   A
```

Basically create a row for each unique user and item occurence. Most of the examples are about counting unique elements but not about actually extracting these. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use `unique` i.e. `unique(DT1)`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944816/unique-on-a-dataframe-with-only-selected-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique on a dataframe with only selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944816/unique-on-a-dataframe-with-only-selected-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dplyr solution that should get those results

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(user = c(rep("userID1",3), rep("userID2",2)), 
                 group = c("A","A","B","A","A"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df <- df %>% 
      group_by(user, group) %>% 
      filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: In this instance, it may be more convenient to use: `df %>% distinct()`

Comment: That would work too, assuming that there are truly only two columns in the original dataset, If there are really only the two columns in the dataset, then using `df[!duplicated(df),]` from base R would work as well.

Comment: Indeed. If there are more than two columns: `df %>% distinct(user, group, .keep_all = TRUE)`